# Optimizar consulta SQL con múltiples LIKE

Tags: php, sql-server, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta que se ejecuta en un servidor con `SQL SERVER 2014`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.docnum, t0.CardCode,t0.DocDate,t0.NumAtCard,'EMPRESA' AS Origen
    FROM OINV t0
    LEFT JOIN RIN1 t1 ON t0.DocEntry=t1.BaseEntry AND t0.ObjType=t1.BaseType
    WHERE YEAR(t0.docdate)=2019 
    AND MONTH(t0.docdate)= 05
    AND (t0.CardCode like '%100027%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2545%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2585%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2675%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2679%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2738%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2745%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2758%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2765%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2829%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2843%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2906%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2963%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%2988%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%3549%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%3830%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4525%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4571%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4578%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4579%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4588%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4641%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4808%'or t0.CardCode like
    '%4659%')
```

La consulta funciona correctamente.
La pregunta es ¿Cómo puede ser más optima esta consulta?, ya que las sucursales cambiaran dependiendo lo que el usuario seleccione en la interfaz.
Gracias.

Comment: Solo tengo una duda, porque utilizas like? es porque no teclean siempre el código completo? Yo lo que regularmente hago, es obtener el código y guardarlo en una tabla temporal, despues solo le haces join a esa tabla temporal donde el codigo de una tabla A sea igual al de la tabla B.

Comment: Si exactamente, quienes diseñaron la base de datos utilizaron tipos de datos distintos en un lado VARCHAR y en otro INTEGER, ej. Yo de donde tengo que obtener los datos solo puedo capturar un valor numérico "4808" pero en la base de datos de SAP ese codigo es de tipo VARCHAR "CM004808", por esa razón utilizo LIKE

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es crear una función que reciba los códigos, CM004808. Eliminarle las letras al inicio 004808, y el resultado lo puedes castear select cast('004008' as integer). Es lo que se me ocurre ahorita, pero pueden existir soluciones más eficientes. Esta función recibiría una cadena separada por comas y te devolvería una tabla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta es una opción que puede funcionarte. Realice pruebas enviandole 342 códigos a la función de tipo tabla.

Le envías una cadena con todos tus códigos separados por una coma:

'CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800'

En la función proceso el texto primero creando una tabla con los códigos, después le elimino las letras y por ultimo el resultado le elimino los ceros al inicio.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Danilo Luna>
-- Create date: <30/05/2019>
-- Description: <Función para procesar codigos >
-- =============================================
alter FUNCTION dbo.[FnProcesarTexto]
(   
     @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),--delimitado
     @delimiter NVARCHAR(MAX)--delimitador
)
RETURNS @t TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Valor NVARCHAR(MAX), ValorProcesado NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @xml XML

         declare @pos int
         declare @string varchar(max)

         SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'


         INSERT INTO @t(Valor)
         SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
         FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r) OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR ( @xml = null) )

         declare @PRows int, @PContador int=1
         set @PRows=(select max(id) from @t)
                 while @PContador <= @PRows
         begin
            set @string=(select valor from @t where Id=@PContador)
            while isnumeric(@string+'e0') = 0
                begin

                set @pos = (select patindex('%[^0-9]%',@string))
                set @string = (select replace(@string,substring(@string,@pos,1),''))

                set @string= (select substring(@string, patindex('%[^0]%',@string), 10) )

                update @t set Valor=@string  where Id=@PContador

                end
            set @PContador=@PContador + 1
         end

         RETURN
    END
GO
```

De esta forma envías los datos a la función:

```
SELECT id
,valor
FROM dbo.FnProcesarTexto('CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,',')
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: Rows]

Y a la tabla de resultado le haces un join a las tablas que ya tienes para comparar.

```
declare @CodigosProcesados table(
    Id Int,
    Codigo INT
)

insert into @CodigosProcesados(Id,Codigo)
SELECT id
,valor
FROM dbo.FnProcesarTexto('CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89900,CM004808,CM004809,XY89600,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,
CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800,CM004808,CM004709,XY89800,CM004808,CM004809,XY89800', ',')


declare @OINV table (
    DocNum int,
    CardCode int,
    DocDate datetime
)

insert into @OINV (DocNum,CardCode,DocDate)values(1,'4809',getdate())
insert into @OINV (DocNum,CardCode,DocDate)values(2,'89800',getdate())

select distinct(t0.DocNum) 
from @OINV t0
inner join @CodigosProcesados b on t0.CardCode=b.Codigo
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

No se tardó ni un segundo en procesar la información. Aún así si te parece mi respuesta, trata de optimizar su funcionamiento, ya que siempre hay mejores formas de resolver los problemas.

Comment: Gracias, funciono muy bien y de manera más eficiente en comparación con el query que tenia.

Answer (score 2):

Esto te puede servir.

Usando esta función de números:

```html
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.ufn_GetNums', N'IF') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ufn_GetNums;

go
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Itzik's VATN
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_GetNums(@low AS bigint, @high AS bigint) 
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (

 WITH
 L0 AS (SELECT c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
 L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
 L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
 L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
 L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
 L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
 Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum FROM L5)
 SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS rowNumber
 FROM Nums
 ORDER BY rownum
);
GO
```

Para luego remover los caracteres.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(CardCode, rowNumber, 1)
    FROM    dbo.ufn_GetNums(1,20)
    WHERE   rowNumber > 0 AND rowNumber <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(CardCode))
            AND SUBSTRING(CardCode, rowNumber, 1) NOT like ('%[^0-9]%')
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS cod
FROM
(
              select 'CM2545'   CardCode 
    union all select 'CM2585'
    union all select 'CM2675'
    union all select 'CM2679'
    union all select 'CM2738'
    union all select 'CM2745'
    union all select 'CM2758'
    union all select 'CSSDM2765'
    union all select 'CM2829'
    union all select 'CM2843'
    union all select 'CDSDSDM2906'
    union all select 'CM2963'
    union all select 'CM2988'
    union all select 'CM3549'
    union all select 'CM3830'
    union all select 'CM4525'
    union all select 'CMXZXZ4571'
    union all select 'CM4578'
    union all select 'CM4579'
    union all select 'CM4588'
    union all select 'CM4641'
    union all select 'CM4808'
    union all select 'CM4659'
)t
```

Esto es bastante eficiente.